# TypeError: this.props.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I would like to say that I know there are many questions regarding this topic. I read through most of them and I double and triple checked my code but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have the following child component, which contains an image, which you can change by clicking on said image (you can iterate through an array of 5 images).

```
export default class Images extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.changeIcon = this.changeIcon.bind(this);
        this.state = {pointer: this.props.id-1, imgs: props.imgs };
    }

    changeIcon () {
        const {length} = this.state.imgs;
        const {pointer } = this.state;
        const newPointer = pointer === length - 1 ? 0 : pointer+1;
        this.setState({ pointer: newPointer });
        this.props.onChangeIcon("I work");
    }

    render() {
        const isclicked = this.props.clicked;
        const { pointer, imgs } = this.state;
        return(
            <img src={imgs[pointer]} onClick={this.changeIcon}/>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the parent component:

```
import Images from "./images";

class Displayer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.changeIcons = this.changeIcons.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            imgs = [link1, link2, link3, link4, link5]
        }
    }
    changeIcons(word) {
        console.log(word);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Images onChangeIcon={this.changeIcons} imgs={this.state.imgs}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

The weird thing is, that it works perfectly fine with another function inside the same child component. I used the same structure and I also double-checked for any spelling mistakes, but nothing helped.

I still receive the same error message `TypeError: this.props.changeIcon is not a function`. Am I missing something? Can anyone spot a mistake?

Edit: the id-prop is added at another point. In order so keep it simple I did not include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`changeIcons` doesn't belong to props but just a method of your component

Instead of this:

```
<Images onChangeIcon={this.props.changeIcons}
```

Try this:

```
<Images onChangeIcon={this.changeIcons}
```

UPDATE:

Try to use arrow function in the callback to see where the problem is:

```
return (
    <img src={imgs[pointer]} onClick={() => this.changeIcon() }/>
);
```

Or just turn changeIcon into arrow function:

```
changeIcon = () => {
    const {length} = this.state.imgs;
    const {pointer } = this.state;
    const newPointer = pointer === length - 1 ? 0 : pointer+1;
    this.setState({ pointer: newPointer });
    this.props.onChangeIcon("I work");
}

render() {
    const isclicked = this.props.clicked;
    const { pointer, imgs } = this.state;
    return(
        <img src={imgs[pointer]} onClick={this.changeIcon}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: actually, I made a mistake in copying my code there. I just wrote that up quickly in order to not let it become to long and accidentally wrote this.props.changeIcons. I'll fix that right away and thank you for your help!

Comment: Please double-check your question to ensure there is no more mistakes. It seems there is another mistake in the constructor. instead of  `this.changeIcon = this.changeIcon.bind(this)`, it should be `this.changeIcon = this.props.onChangeIcon.bind(this)`

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that is? I'm binding the `changeIcon()` function in the child component, which calls the `onChangeIcon` prop in the child's constructor method, same goes for the function in the parent component. Why would I bind `onChangeIcon`?

Comment: @A.S.J ahh, I understand

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately, that didn't work either, however, I'm pretty sure now that there's an issue with the `this.props.onChangeIcon();`-call, since, when trying to copy & paste it into other functions that were created following the same structure, I got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have done mistake in constructor function. pass imgs and ids also as you are using in child component. Do it like this

```
import Images from "./images";

class Displayer extends React.Component {
    changeIcons = (word) => {
        console.log(word);
    }
    state = {
     imgs : ["img1","img2", "img3"],
     id: 0,
    }
//Here i dont know how you are getting img urls array.Please add your code accordingly
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Images imgs={this.state.imgs} onChangeIcon={this.changeIcons} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

And thats it, now it should work.

Comment: I tried to implement what you said, however, I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: `Images.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onChangeIcon is not a function`, same as earlier

Comment: This should not happen strange, but can you console.log this.props in the changeIcon function in Images component